# Is it possible to work in Germany with a small criminal history?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, legal, criminal-records

I am not yet convicted of a crime but I am being charged with a felony that will most likely be reduced to a misdemeanor with a year probation here in the United States. It's non violent, and not drug, theft, or firearm related that took place over two years ago. But yet it doesn't quality to be expunged.

It's basically trespassing but I'm fearful of my chances of moving to Berlin in the future when I graduate university.

Is it possible to get a visa and move to Germany with this on my record? Perhaps if I get a certificate of good conduct?

Answer (score 1):

It'll most likely depend on the officer reviewing your application, however, you could include some references from people (do you know any cops, or lawyers?) saying you're basically a great person.

[It's noted that Germany does have some rules on applicants with a criminal history](http://wikitravel.org/en/Travelling_with_a_criminal_history):

> Countries like Germany have specific rules that state anyone convicted
>   of an offense relating to public order with a sentence of more than 3
>   years, a drug offense with a sentence of more than 2 years, and any
>   offense related to alien smuggling is deport-able (a "must deport").
>   Like the UK they are more concerned with offenses committed in their
>   country, rather than outside of the EU.

Whatever you do though, don't lie to any officials in person or on paper. If you're caught lying, you're basically stuffed.  It might also be worth getting an immigration lawyer to help, as they'll have further ideas on how to polish up your application to make you sound good.